# Firebase Database Push is generating Key but changes is not showing on

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create Node Js server in which upon calling a particular rest api it will change some data in firebase.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var admin = require("firebase");

admin.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: './<some-name>nsdk-dgimw-1cab1079fa.json',
  databaseURL: "https://<some-name>.firebaseio.com"
});

// define a simple route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to EasyNotes application. Take notes quickly. Organize and keep track of all your notes."});
});

app.get('/getMe', function(req, res){
    var ref = admin.database().ref();
    var childBlog = ref.child('/bloggers');
    // var userRef = childBlog.push();


    var userRef = childBlog.push({
        name: 'Christopher',
        description: 'I eat too much ice cream'
    });
    console.log('user key', userRef.key);

    var myInt = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    }, 10000);
});

// listen for requests
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

This particular piece of code is creating a server and rest api call is working fine. But as I inserted firebase push code, it logs the push key generated but when I visit firebase database I find no changes.

I followed this [article](https://howtofirebase.com/save-and-query-firebase-data-ed73fb8c6e3a)

I want to figure out if I am doing correct thing and if not what would be the correct solution?

Database Structure--

```
-tech-bloggie
  -articles
  -bloggers
  -comments



Warning :
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND accounts.google.com accounts.google.com:443\"."}
```

Comment: Does your database have the `/bloggers` child?

Comment: @ShababbKarim yes i have bloggers as child in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected SDK is firebase-admin

```
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
```

So, in your case it would be:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

Updating the SDK, your code works as expected:

Your updated code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./config/serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://shining-fire-7601.firebaseio.com"
});

// define a simple route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to EasyNotes application. Take notes quickly. Organize and keep track of all your notes."});
});

app.get('/getMe', function(req, res){
    var ref = admin.database().ref();
    var childBlog = ref.child('/bloggers');
    // var userRef = childBlog.push();


    var userRef = childBlog.push({
        name: 'Christopher',
        description: 'I eat too much ice cream'
    });
    console.log('user key', userRef.key);

    var myInt = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    }, 10000);
});

// listen for requests
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

The expected console log output:

```
# node stack
Server is listening on port 9084
user key -L82E-smqbJ7CDMBXK4K
Hello
user key -L82ETNDTdGa6jZqbFQ1
Hello
user key -L82Ex-SWQq_hPV1YRBt
Hello
```

And the firebase console:

[image]

Note about your warning: The SDK must be configured properly: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=en-419

Basically, you are needing this:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: '<PROJECT_ID>',
    clientEmail: 'foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
  }),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

This is what you need to do:

"*Initialize the SDK - Once you have created a Firebase console project and downloaded a JSON file with your service account credentials, you can initialize the SDK with this code snippet...*"

Comment: what is colectorDB?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala please try my updated answer and let me know

Comment: yes i am trying it again, I have tried it earlier but not geting any response

Comment: but I am getting one warning

Comment: I have added the warning above.

Comment: you need to configure the SDK properly: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=en-419

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala No, I'm able to reproduce your issue. Thing is, you are not authenticating to your firebase database, that part is missing in your code. To use the Firebase Admin SDKs, you'll need a Firebase project (you have it already), a service account to communicate with the Firebase service, and a configuration file with your service account's credentials. These last #2 items are what you need.

Comment: The issue was authentication issue and that occuring due to proxy networks because currently firebase doesnot support proxy